# How do I display the index position of a post from a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, get-posts

So I have a custom post type (ex. songs) and have a few posts that I created for this post type.

I want to display them on a webpage in order (ex. 1, 2, 3, ...). How do I get the index position and display it on my page?

Any insight or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You mean pagination? What exactly do you mean by index position?

Comment: Are you talking about *both* changing the order and displaying the index position, or only one of the two? Also, is the index position meant to be a ID/primary key of some kind, or is it determined according to the song's place in the final list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to add a custom field to the posts. Call it index_position or something similar. Create a nice meta_box if you want the client to be happy.

Then, when you query for posts in your template, ask for posts sorted by your custom field in a meta_query:

```
$song_query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'songs',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_key' => 'index_position',
    )
);
```